# Logging Strategies with mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library

good day, I am writting something that will be extended in multiple upcoming releases. The only reason now I'm mentioning this is because new functionality included in the controllers will have to be traced and logged for:

**Examples**

1. Release 0.0 - one method that gets some info..need to log just the fact that it was hit and capture the Http Request's identity (guaranteed to be authenticated by that time):

StockController:

```
   ///I dont want to use the var LogWriter logger 
   ///EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>()
   ///Instead I would like to use injection and just deco the method with something like this
   [CaptureMethodVisit4Loggin(Category.Info, captureIdentity=true, trace = true)]
   ViewResult Index() 
   {
        var stuff = ServiceLocator.GetMyComponent<ForStuff>();
        return View(stuff.GetAll());

   }
```

2 Release 1.0 - Adding some new methods that require some elevated permissions to access to the existing controller class:

StockController:

```
   ///Same here - I dont want to write logging code with every new release instead
   ///all methods on the controller should by default have the 
   [CaptureReadWriteMethodVisitForLogging(Category.Info, trackID = true, trace = true)]
   ActionResult RegisterStock(int registrarID, Ticker ticker) 
   {

         //do some crazy stuff.

   }
```

And so it goes... New methods get introduced - some might not have the attribute - in this case they will get some default logging output.

Is this possible to achieve with EntLib 5.0?